# What’s the difference between definite assignment assertion and ambient declaration?

Tags: typescript, initialization, type-assertion, typescript-class

When asserting that a field is definitely initialized in a class, what’s the difference between `!` (exclamation point, definite assignment assertion) and the `declare` modifier?

The following code is an error in strict mode since TS doesn’t know for sure that the field has been initialized.

```js
class Person {
    name: string; // Error: Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
}
```

I’ve seen 2 ways of handling this:

1. Definite assignment assertion:

   ```js
   class Person {
       name!: string;
   }
   ```
2. Ambient declaration:

   ```js
   class Person {
       declare name: string;
   }
   ```

I can’t see the difference between these two techniques. They both cure the error, they both don’t emit code, and they both don’t allow initializers. Does [ambient declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) (released in v3.7) simply outdate [definite assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) (released in v2.7)? Should `declare` be used instead of `!` whenever possible?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Declare is mainly useful for mocking values when playing around with the type system. In production code, it's rarely used.

---

```
declare name: string;
```

This says to the compiler:

> *"There is a property called `name` of type `string`. I shouldn't have to prove to you that `name` actually exists, but I want to use it anyway."*

The `declare` keyword is typically used in type definition files that provide typings for files that Typescript cannot get type information from (such as plain JS files). So if I was reading your code, I would assume that `name` is getting monkey patched in from some JS file somewhere, and you are noting that here.

I would be incorrect.

---

```
name!: string;
```

This says to the compiler:

> *"There is a property called `name` with a type of `string | undefined`. It starts with a value of `undefined`. But every time I get or set that property, I want to treat it as type `string`."*

Using this form it's clear to anyone reading the code that `name` is undefined at first, but is treated like a string anyway. That means it must be set in this file somewhere, just probably not in the constructor.

From what you are saying, I would be correct in those assumptions.

---

In practice, in *this particular case*, the result is nearly identical. In both cases you have a string property that you never have to actually initialize. However, I would argue that the `name!: string` is far more clear about what is actually going on.

Also, `declare` *never* emits code. It makes something only exist in the type system. *(Thanks for mentioning this @NoelDeMartin)*

```
class Foo {
    bar!: string;
    declare baz: string;
}

let bar: string
declare let baz: string
```

Compiles to:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        Object.defineProperty(this, "bar", {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: void 0
        });
    }
}
let bar;
```

Note that `baz` is completely absent from the output.

---

Lastly though, I have to mention, you should probably just refactor your code so that you can assign the property in the constructor. Both those methods are not as type safe since you could potentially treat an uninitialized value as a `string`, which will likely cause a crash if it happens.

Comment: I've been running into an issue recently that was solved by using `declare` instead of the assertion. That is to say, there is some difference in practice depending on your configuration. For example, I'm using `esnext` target and this activates the [useDefineForClassFields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#useDefineForClassFields) configuration. Here's an example in the Typescript playground showcasing how the output is different: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQrqegIzAJwEIAuaCAFzwEsA7AcwG4MsATAU1H1ZzAC8TyqdRlmjoAvkA